# getting the source code of a website dynamically with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

I wish to get the code of a website as you can with "view source" but dynamically.
I found a site which does exactly what i want - http://www.iwebtool.com but I wish
to implement it by myself.
any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chould give this a try in a php page:

```
<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<xmp>
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); ?>
</xmp>
</body>
</html>
```

You could replace 'http://www.google.com' with the value of a variable you can set dynamically.

Comment: thanks, didn't knwo there was something so usefull as XMP

Comment: xmp is completly deprecated. don't use it. use <pre>

Comment: so thats why I didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

`<xmp>` is deprecated also you should take care of html special chars so I'd go with:

```
<pre>
    <?php echo htmlentities( file_get_contents( 'http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.html' ) ); ?>
</pre>
```